# Visual Studio - Go to Implementation of Interface by default

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

In visual studio with resharper there is a command "Go to implementation" when you are hovering over an interface.

By default if you press F12 it will go to definition, on interfaces this is almost never what you want though.

What I would like, Press F12 on a method, it goes to the definition. Press F12 on an interface, it performs "Go To implementation" not "got to definition".

Is there anyway I can script this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Using the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+F12` will take you to implementation, if there is only one, otherwise it will open a Implementation Search, listing all the implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure the shortcuts.

Goto Tools-> Options -> Key Board -> Search for the command and assign a key. I use this shortcut most of the times when I wanted to look at the implementation.

Comment: I can already do that, the issue is I want the same key to do both actions depending on whether it is an interface or a method.

Comment: F12 by default already does that. If it's an interface, it will take you to the interface. If it's just a class, it will take you to the class.

Comment: Yes I don't want it to take me to the interface, I want it to take me to the implementation.